# Is it possible to debug lua script that runs C libraries using Xcode?

Tags: c++, c, xcode, debugging, lua

I have code in C/C++ that I builds using make file. The shared library is then used by a lua script which calls the function in the library. I wish to use the Xcode's power of debugging (GUI in particular). Is it possible to do this. I dont mind converting the makefile into a Xcode project but how do I deal with lua? I wish to debug the library and the lua script. Thank you.

Comment: https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-lua-debugging

Comment: Looks good for lua, Thanks.